# PowerShell "-like" not comparing true for identically printing strings

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my PowerShell script, I'm having a problem comparing the output of the `wsl --list --all` (Windows Subsystem for Linux) command using the `-like` operator. It simply will not compare as `$true` even though it prints to the console as if it should. It seems to be an encoding problem, but I am at a loss as to what encoding to use or how to go about converting this correctly. Can someone shed light on this for me?

```
$distros = wsl --list --all 
    
foreach ($distro in $distros) {
    Write-Host "Checking: '$distro' -like 'Ubuntu*' => $($distro -like 'Ubuntu*')"
}
```

Results in:

```
Checking: 'Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: 'Ubuntu-22.04 (Default)' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: 'rancher-desktop' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: 'rancher-desktop-data' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
Checking: '' -like 'Ubuntu*' => False
```

Not to mention the random empty strings above given that the console output of `wsl` has none of that:

```
> wsl --list --all
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-22.04 (Default)
rancher-desktop
rancher-desktop-data
```

I have managed to wrangle it to compare properly using the following, but it just seems wrong to have to jump through hoops like this just to get it to convert, not to mention not really being correct, especially if a double-byte char is emitted by `wsl`:

```
$distros = $distros.ForEach(
    {
        $utf8.GetString(
            $utf16.GetBytes($_).ForEach(
                {
                    if ($_ -ne 0) {
                        return $_
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `wsl.exe`'s output for `--help` and distro-management commands such as `--list` defaults to UTF-16LE, causing PowerShell to mis-decode it.
The simplest solution is to set `$env:WSL_UTF8=1` beforehand. See the linked duplicate for details.